# Knockout.js pulling element from observableArray returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Here is the code I am using in a larger function:

```
this.categoriesToSearch = ko.observableArray(["Food"]);// Initial selection
console.log(this.categoriesToSearch[0]);
```

Running this returns `undefined`. Knockout.js documentation says observableArrays are supposed to be read that way. Is there a better way to read observableArrays?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question since I came up with the answer right after posting: observableArrays are functions so the correct way to pull an item is:

```
this.categoriesToSearch()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.categoriesToSearch()[0]`

KO documentation says you have to handle observable array like a function call.